# Unable to POST Json to REST service

Tags: jquery, json, wcf, rest

It looks like I can post text to my REST service, but I can't post json or text that looks like json, and I can't figure out why.  At the bottom I've included two different Ajax bits, one that works (only passing a string) and one that doesn't  (passing a string that's Json).  The error I get when it doesn't work is "Method Not Allowed", but I suspect that's because it's trying to POST to the GET method...at least, that's what it feels like.  The GET works fine.  Also, I can repro this in fiddler.

**Contract:**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IUser
{
    [ OperationContract ]
    [ WebGet (UriTemplate = "" , ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    MyUserObject GetUser();

    [ OperationContract ]
    [ WebInvoke (UriTemplate = "{userToUpdate}" , Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat .Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle .WrappedRequest)]
    void UpdateUser(string userToUpdate);
}
```

**Class:**

```
   [ AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode .Allowed)]
[ ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode .PerCall)]
public class User : IUser
{

    [ WebGet (UriTemplate = "" , ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public MyUserObject GetUser()
    {
        UserState thisSessionManager = new UserState();
        MyUserObject returnMe = thisSessionManager.GetCurrentUser();
        return returnMe;
    }


    [ WebInvoke (UriTemplate = "{userToUpdate}" , Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat .Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle .WrappedRequest)]
    public void UpdateUser( string userToUpdate)
    {
       ///here I'm just logging the text value
    }

}
```

}

Routing:

```
    private void RegisterRoutes()
    {
        WebServiceHostFactory factory = new WebServiceHostFactory();
        RouteTable .Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute( "services/user" , factory, typeof (BigHistory.Services.User )));
    }
```

**Ajax that doesn't work:**

```
    var passthis = JSON.stringify(thisUser);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST" ,
        url: "/services/user" ,
        data: "{ 'userToUpdate':'" + passthis + "'}" ,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" ,
        dataType: "json" ,
        async: true ,
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

**Ajax that does work ("xyz123" is logged by the correct function in the class):**

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST" ,
        url: "/services/user/xyz123" ,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" ,
        dataType: "text" ,
        async: true ,
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

**Coinfig:**

```
 <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
<services>
  <service name="MyName.Services.User" behaviorConfiguration="myServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint name="webHttpBinding" address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyName.Services.IUser" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp"></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name ="myServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name ="webHttp">
      <webHttp/>

    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

**The object, as passed to the console:**

```
{"Email":"","FirstName":"Joe","IHaveSeenMyProfilePage":false}
```

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed this:

```
UriTemplate = "{userToUpdate}"
```

To this:

```
UriTemplate = ""
```

And all is well.